# Move overlayed points' legend to the bottom of the legend list

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, overlay

A follow-up of [Overlay dots on a stacked bar chart and include a legend key on blank background for the dots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76139251/overlay-dots-on-a-stacked-bar-chart-and-include-a-legend-key-on-blank-background)

I need "Average price" at the bottom of the legend list.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
```

A dummy df for the dots

```
price.avg <- diamonds %>%
  group_by(cut, color) %>%
  summarise(price = mean(price), dummy = "1")
```

Main plot

```
diamonds %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(x = cut, fill = clarity)) +
  facet_wrap(~ color, scale="free_y") +
  ylab("Count") +
  xlab("Cut") + 
  geom_point(data = price.avg, aes(x = cut, y = price, col = "")) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~. * 1, name = "price")) + 
  scale_color_manual(name = "", label = "Average price", values = "black")
```

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the ordering with the `guides()` function, consult the [documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/guides.html) for other helpful hints.

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(ggplot2)

price.avg <- diamonds %>%
  group_by(cut, color) %>%
  summarise(price = mean(price), dummy = "1")
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'cut'. You can override using the `.groups`
#> argument.

diamonds %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(x = cut, fill = clarity)) +
  facet_wrap(~ color, scale="free_y") +
  ylab("Count") +
  xlab("Cut") + 
  geom_point(data = price.avg, aes(x = cut, y = price, col = "")) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~. * 1, name = "price")) + 
  scale_color_manual(name = "", label = "Average price", values = "black")+ 
  guides(
    color = guide_legend(order = 2), 
    fill = guide_legend(order = 1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>